# Как из одного потока уведомить другой поток

Tags: ооп, потоки-данных, дизайн

Такая ситуация.
Есть два потока. 
Первый поток выполняет чтение из файла, второй, основной поток (класс окна), хендлит действия пользователя, (запускает первый поток) и содержит GUI поток.
Первый поток не может вызывать никакое API для работы с GUI.
Допустим, возникает ошибка в первом потоке (чтение файла).
И мы хотим уведомить пользователя о произошедшей ситуации.
Как это лучше сделать?

Какие идеи возникли у меня:

1. Самое простое. Заинжектить поинтер на класс, который может работать с GUI, в класс потока и через него вызывать все нужные нотификации. Минусы: все обработчики (всю логику) связанные с ошибками в потоке ответственном за чтение и обработку файла придется лепить в классе окна, что, как мне кажется, не есть гуд. Плюс возникает стрикт депенденси, что, как мне кажется, тоже не очень хорошо.
2. Вынести логику хендлинга ошибок в отдельный класс, заинжектить и создать его экземляр в главном классе (классе окна), и через прокси дергать обработчики ошибки (тоже как-то криво. получается класс окна все равно заполнится методами, связанными с обработкой ошибок в потоке чтения файла).

Comment: первый выглядит мутно и похоже он плохой.

По факту, как я бы делал. Рабочий поток в случае ошибки просто выставляет код возврата (одно число типа int) и текстовое описание ошибки, потом закрывает файлы (и делает очистку выделенных ресурсов) и завершается. Ему больше делать нечего. Главный поток, получив уведомление о завершении рабочего потока читает код ошибки и выводит его пользователи/записывает в файл/перезапускает поток.

Как следствие - никаких зависимостей (ну кроме того, что главный поток должен сделать join или обработать сообщение о завершении). Каждый поток делает свою работу.

Comment: есть 2 варианта решения проблемы, смотрите дизайнт паттерны: медиатор и обсервер. для того чтоб операции нотификации происходили не в основном потоке вам придется использовать пул потоков чтоб каждое сообщение приходило в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @jmu, а чем Вам простое и надежное (*для описанной задачи*) предложение @KoVadim, не нравится?

Зачем все усложнять-то?

Comment: @avp: например, записывание кода ошибки в глобальную переменную означает с лёту то, что с таким дизайном одновременно запустить _два_ задания невозможно. Плюс UI-поток должен заниматься запуском рабочего потока, что не должно входить в его обязанности.

Comment: @VladD, здесь же определенно речь **об одном задании**. И потом, мы же с Вами знаем, что в программировании надо раздельно рассматривать понятия: *один, два и много*.

Но, конечно, более надежным (и в то же время простым) будет возврат значения из потока в виде указателя на динамическую память.

--

А почему UI поток не должен сам запускать другие потоки? В таком дизайне (если не должен) потребуется по крайней мере еще один поток -- диспетчер и интерфейс UI с ним.

Comment: @avp: Ну, мне лично не очень нравится плохо расширяемый дизайн.

Вопрос не в том, _из какого_ потока запускается рабочий поток, вопрос в том, что UI-код не должен об этом заботиться. Асинхронное задание должно **само** заботиться о том, где и как оно будет выполняться, это его ответственность.

Comment: @VladD, если вопрос не в том, какой поток, тогда это вопрос, где проводить границу между UI и прочим кодом.

Очевидно, красиво написанная программа долджна состоять из модулей (желательно разумно разнесенных по файлам/каталогам) и один из UI модулей вызывает функцию в модуле "диспетчера заданий" и т.д. Тут, собственно, спорить-то не о чем. 

--

А errno чем так ужасна? Для каждого потока своя.

Comment: @avp: В правильно структурированной программе UI лишь сообщает уровню «бизнес-логики» о том, что случилось, а там уж принимаются решения о том, что надо сделать.

---
Проблема `errno` в том, что вызов каждой функции **обязан** быть окружён boilerplate-кодом:

    errno = 0;
    int result = some_func();
    if (errno != 0)
    {
        //* здесь result невалиден
    }
    else
    {
        // использовать result
    }
    // здесь result невалиден

То есть я вынужден либо писать wrapper для каждой функции, либо писать код, который _говорит_ не то, что я _намерен_ сделать.

Comment: @VladD, немного уточню. Вызов каждой функции, *в результатах которого, Вы* ***не уверены***.

На самом деле надо по возможности проверять внешние входные данные (да, к сожалению это не всегда в полной мере возможно). После адекватного анализа большая часть параноидальных проверок не нужна.

--

Я понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать про вброс и обработку исключений. Иногда (особенно в *примерах*) это удобно. На деле же, в большой программе, для осмысленной диагностики и восстановления потребуется столько же кода, только в другом месте (catch, finally).

Comment: @avp:

1) А много ли найдётся функций, в результате которых вы _уверены_?

2) Исключения гораздо лучше хотя бы тем, что я могу вызвать 15 функций, и окружить их единственным блоком try/catch. Причём этот блок может быть не сразу около вызова, а на том уровне, который по моему замыслу должен обрабатывать ошибки. А с `errno` мне придётся передавать код ошибки на 5 уровней вверх, ужасно уродливо + простор для ошибок в стиле «не проверил код возврата, использовал неинициализированное значение».

Comment: @avp: плюс после исключения я не могу продолжить выполнение функции как ни в чём ни бывало, проигнорировав ошибку. Для этого мне понадобится явный и осознанный `try {...} catch (everything) {}`.

Comment: > Зачем все усложнять-то?

@avp собственно я не читал предыдущий коммент. з.ы. не считаю изучение и исопльзование паттернов усложнением кода, чирз :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы не подсмотреть решение у уже существующей системы?

Примеры ([отсюда](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)):

1. **Background Worker**. Создаёте класс, в котором можно подставлять пользовательский код (например, через события или виртуальные функции): `DoWork` (работает в фоновом потоке, выполняет всю работу), `ProgressChanged` (вызывается в главном потоке, получает аргументом текущий процент выполненной работы), `WorkCompleted` (вызывается в главном потоке, получает аргументом результат выполнения, и признак успеха), предоставляет функцию `Cancel` (которая выставляет флаг, который в свою очередь должен проверяться кодом в `DoWork`).
2. **Task**. Объект, представляющий собой задание, выполняющееся в данный момент, и поставляющее результат, возможно, в будущем. Задание представляет собой пользовательский код (делегат, но вполне можно и виртуальную функцию/событие/whatever), возвращающий значение результирующего типа, и выполняющийся в отдельном потоке (на самом деле, всё чуточку сложнее, но можно игнорировать пока). К заданию можно «прикрепить» в качестве *продолжения* другое задание, которое будет выполнено, например, в главном потоке. Прикреплённые задания могут быть разными для случая успешного и неуспешного выполнения основного задания, и получают на вход результат основного задания.

Код на C#:

1.

```
var filename = @"C:\A Study in Scarlet.txt";
var bw = new BackgroundWorker
{
    WorkerReportsProgress = false,
    WorkerSupportsCancellation = false
};
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{
    // in background thread
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filename);
    var filteredLines = lines.Where(l => l.Contains("Holmes"));
    args.Result = filteredLines.Count();
};

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    // in UI thread
    if (args.Error != null)
        ShowError(args.Error.Message);
    else
        ShowResult(args.Result);
};

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

2.

```
var t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filename);
    var filteredLines = lines.Where(l => l.Contains("Holmes"));
    return filteredLines.Count();
};

t.ContinueWith(ShowResult,
               TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
               TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
t.ContinueWith(prev => ShowError(prev.Exception.Message),
               TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
               TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```